# Setting up Bind DNS on WIndows 7

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, windows-7, bind

I have Apache running on Windows 7. Now I'm trying to get Bind DNS working.

Here is my db.eg.com.txt file

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL 604800
@ IN SOA ns.eg.com. root.eg.com. (
                              1 ; Serial
                         604800 ; Refresh
                          86400 ; Retry
                        2419200 ; Expire
                         604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@ IN NS ns.eg.com.
@ IN A 172.16.5.1
ns IN A 172.16.5.1
```

and my named.conf file:

```
options {
directory "c:\named\zones";
allow-transfer { none; };
recursion no;
};

zone "eg.com" IN {
type master;
file "db.eg.com.txt";
allow-transfer { none; };
};


controls {
inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};
```

I'm doing this pretty blindly, as I don't know what 'ns' in 'ns.eg.com' and 'root' in 'root.eg.com' should be replaced with in the db.eg.com.txt file. When I go to eg.com it just takes me to 127.0.0.1 instead of 172.16.5.1

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: To what avail do you install all this on Windows where you can simpler get it on Linux? This is where it was designed for.

Comment: Perhaps there is not a Linux server readily available, or they simply have more familiarity with Windows and don't want to spend days learning a whole new operating system just to get a DNS server online.  BIND works just as well on Windows as it does on Linux once it's configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check and remove eg.com from hosts-file

Restart Bind

Verify if Bind listen on 53 port

```
nslookup
 > server localhost
 > eg.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Your named.conf lists the domain as `eg.com` but the `SOA` record in the file lists `ns.eg.com.` which doesn't match up.  Change the `SOA` record in `db.eg.com.txt` file to `eg.com.` and restart BIND (or reload its configuration).

Essentially what you're doing here is defining start of authority on a hostname of the zone rather than the zone itself.  Without a proper `SOA` record for the zone, BIND will be unable to load the configuration for the zone properly.